# Validate File Upload in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, mean-stack

I am Brad, I am new to ReactJS currently i am working on ant-design form. I want to validate the input file validation for empty file input fields and display the message "please attach a file", I am not able to write code for this module please help me and i am very stuck

**My Form Code**

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { Upload, message, Button, Icon } from 'antd';

const PhotoText = styled.div`
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 2rem 0 1rem 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: -webkit-auto;
`;

const ButtonWrapper = styled.div`
  text-align: center;
`;

let file = { id: 'test' };
const { propss } = {
  name: 'file',
  action: '//jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/',
  headers: {
    authorization: 'authorization-text',
  },
  onChange(info) {
    file = info.file;
    if (info.file.status !== 'uploading') {
    }
    if (info.file.status === 'done') {
      message.success(`${info.file.name} file uploaded successfully`);
      file = info.file;
    } else if (info.file.status === 'error') {
      message.error(`${info.file.name} file upload failed.`);
    }
  },
};
class RegisterStepTwo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.saveData = this.saveData.bind(this);
  }

  saveData(e) {
    this.props.addData(e, file);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <PhotoText>Select a Photo to Upload</PhotoText>
        <Upload {...propss}>
          <Button>
            <Icon type="upload" /> Click to Upload
          </Button>
        </Upload>
        <br />
        <PhotoText>Select a Video to Upload</PhotoText>
        <Upload {...propss}>
          <Button>
            <Icon type="upload" /> Click to Upload
          </Button>
        </Upload>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default RegisterStepTwo;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for [beforeUpload](https://ant.design/components/upload/) function (scroll down a bit).

Add that function to props and check the content of form inside it (validate it). According to the docs, returning false should stop the upload.

**Edit:** 
I really shouldn't write code for you. Anyway, something like this should work:

```
const { propss } = {
    ...code you've got so far,
    beforeUpdate(file) {
        if (file === '') {
            message.error('your error message');
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

[There is an an example](https://ant.design/components/upload/#components-upload-demo-upload-manually) - click on `< >` symbol to see the code.
Before upload function takes file argument, adds it to the list, and returns false, thus preventing upload. User needs to press the button to do so.
You should instead check the variable (if it's not empty), show a message (message.error()) and return false.

Comment: can you please add this Functionality to my code that i able to display error message